# Error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" - heroku deployment

Tags: python, github, heroku, deployment, plotly-dash

Hi I am new to heroku and I am trying to deploy a plotly-dash app from github. While the app is deploying with no errors, when I click the url, I am getting the following error message:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
```

The heroku logs output:

```
2024-01-03T11:13:34.000Z casino-5f heroku/router at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=casino-5f-958d8779bafe.herokuapp.com request_id=9ab8e8a8-7d7d-4059-a5a3-1b9735cee671 fwd="2.86.68.160" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My file structure is:

```
.venv
MyCSVApp
-->src
   -->__init__.py
   -->app.py
   -->Procfile
   -->data
      -->data.csv
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

The code in my Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn app:server
```

My dash app is:

```
# Dash Board
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

# Declare server for Heroku deployment. Needed for Procfile.
server = app.server

# Define the layout of the dashboard
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id="tabs", value='personal', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Player Data', value='personal'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Table Data', value='global'),
    ]),
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
])

# Callback to switch between subpages
@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'), Input('tabs', 'value'))
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'personal':
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='Player',
                options=[{'label': person, 'value': person} for person in namelist],
                value=namelist[1]  # Set the default value
            ),
            html.Div(id='current-profit'),
            html.Div(id='session-progress'),       
            html.Div(id='monthly-progress'),  # Container for the monthly personal data
            html.Div(id='gauge-chart'),  # Container for the gauge charts
        ])
    elif tab == 'global':
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='row-dropdown',
                options=[{'label': '{1} - Session {0}'.format(i+1, pd.to_datetime(dftime2.index.values[i]).strftime('%d-%b')), 'value': i} for i in range(dftime2.shape[0])],
                value=dftime2.shape[0]-2,  # Default to the last game
                style={'width': '50%'}
            ),
            html.Div(id='results-table-container', style={'margin-bottom': '50px'}),  # Change id to 'results-table-container'
            dcc.Checklist(
                id='Name-Checklist',
                options=[{'label': person, 'value': person} for person in namelist],
                value=namelist[:5],  # Select the first 5 people from the namelist
                labelStyle={'font-size': '24px',},  # Increase font size and center labels
                inline=True,
            ),
            html.Div(id='bar-plot'),
            html.Div(id='time-lapse'),
        ])
###
relevant callbacks
###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
    #app.run_server(port=8050, threaded=False)
```

The resources tab on heroku says:

```
This app has no process types yet
Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types. Learn more
```

The app runs locally. Do you know what is causing the error message I am getting?

Comment: Are you using paid or free plan?

Comment: I was using a free plan, but got the 5$/month plan to see if that was the issue. Still nt running. In the recources tab is says: "This app has no process types yet
Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types. Learn more".

Comment: So it looks like it does not recognise your Procfile. Try moving contents of `src` directory to top level directory to see if this is the issue.

Comment: Specifically, `Procfile` *must* be in the top level directory.

Comment: I moved the contents of the src to top level directory. It works now, but for some reason it still reads "This app has no process types ...etc." I think I am going to contact support. Thanks a lot for your help really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Did you *import gunicorn* in app.py? I'm not 100% sure it's needed, but I do always include it. There may also be useful diagnostics on your Heroku dashboard - build logs can be viewed under the 'activity' tab